# How to loop over pair of files in bash?

Tags: linux, bash

I have a bunch of files and these files come with pair. 
For example:

```
File1_1.tar.gz, File1_2.tar.gz
File2_1.tar.gz, File2_2.tar.gz
...
```

I take first pair and execute bunch of commands and get output, then I proceed to second pair. But I can only do this if the folder have two files like `File1_1.tar.gz, File1_2.tar.gz` after that I delete these and add second pair by hand.
I take filenames from directory like this

```
FILE_1=$(ls | sort -n | head -n 1)
FILE_2=$(ls | sort -n | tail -n 1)
```

I would like do it with for loop like take the first two pair get output then take second pair get output and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what you know: each filename has two parts, separated by `_`. The first part is arbitrary, the second part is either `1.tar.gz` or `2.tar.gz`, and the files come in pairs.

This means you can simply iterate over one set, and use parameter expansion to *generate* the (known) other half of the pair.

```
for f1 in *_1.tar.gz; do
    base=${f1%_1.tar.gz}  # Strip _1.tar.gz, leaving File1, File2, etc
    f2=${f1%_1.tar.gz}_2.tar.gz  # add _2.tar.gz to get File1_2.tar.gz, etc
    ...
done
```